# Compiler error: “class, interface, or enum expected”

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have been troubleshooting this program for hours, trying several configurations, and have had no luck. It has been written in java, and has 33 errors (lowered from 50 before)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtphoneNo = +913331234567;
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
        sendSMSMessage();
        }
        });
        }
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

        try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
        }
        }
```

Comment: please tell me this is not your complete code

Comment: It's hard to debug code fragments like these. Can you tell us the line number where you are getting that error?

Comment: You get that message when you are trying to put something in the wrong place. I think we need to see the entire class for this one.

Comment: It shows on every line :(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have an extra close brace ('}') somewhere. This is closing the class, and the compiler is then looking for another class, interface or enum definition

Comment: Yes. I think the extra brace is just above the ---   protected void sendSMSMessage()

Comment: Well, I removed two braces and the errors reduces to 19

Comment: @Adnansaram try indenting your code properly, then you'll be able to spot the error faster.